# Error when starting a React Native app with an Android emulator

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, expo

I have tried several times to launch/run my react native app on android emulator and always getting this error:

```
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: cmd: Can't find service: package
```

Please does any one know or have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you using expo, a blank react native project ? what commands did you provide to start your app ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this following answers ?

- `expo start -c -a`
- `sudo expo start --android`

I found everything on this thread : https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/694